# What does F#'s `box` keyword do and where is it documented?

Tags: f#

The [Null Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/values/null-values) article in the [F# Language Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/) show an example that uses it, but it does not explain what it does exactly.

> You can use the following code to check if an arbitrary value is
> `null`.
>
> ```
> match box value with
> | null -> printf "The value is null."
> | _ -> printf "The value is not null."
> ```

I went through the entire [PDF version](https://learn.microsoft.com/pdf?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Ffsharp%2Ftoc.json) of the language reference, but there is not trace of it ever being introduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`box`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-operators.html#box) and [`unbox`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-operators.html#box) are **operators** documented in the [F# Core API Reference](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/); it tersely states that **they box / unbox (respectively) a strongly typed value**.

- `box a` returns value `a` wrapped in a .NET [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object) instance

  ```
  type Lofa = | A | B

  match      A  with         | :? Lofa -> A //=> error FS0016
  match (box A) with         | :? Lofa -> A //ok
  match (A :> obj)           | :? Lofa -> A //ok
  match (A :> System.Object) | :? Lofa -> A //ok
  ```
- `unbox<a_type> a` will try to unwrap value `a` and cast it into an `a_type` or throw an exception otherwise

For completeness' sake, there is also a [`tryUnbox`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-operators.html#tryUnbox) operator, that can be called the same way as `unbox`, but it returns the boxed value wrapped in an [`Option`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-optionmodule.html).

#### Example use cases

##### 1. Type detection during runtime

The F# for Fun and Profit article [Built-in .NET types](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/cli-types/)<sup>**1**</sup> has an [entire section dedicated to `box` and `unbox`](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/cli-types/#boxing-and-unboxing) which ends with the following example:

<sup>[1]: That is, types of the [Common Language Infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure) (CLI).</sup>

> Let’s say that you want to have a function that matches based on the
> type of the parameter, using the `:?` operator:
>
> ```
> let detectType v =
>     match v with
>         | :? int -> printfn "this is an int"
>         | _ -> printfn "something else"
> ```
>
> Unfortunately, this code will fail to compile, with the following
> error:
>
> ```
> // error  FS0008: This  runtime coercion  or type  test
> // from type  'a to int involves  an indeterminate type
> // based on  information prior  to this  program point.
> // Runtime type  tests are  not allowed on  some types.
> // Further type annotations are needed.
> ```
>
> The message tells you the problem: `runtime type tests are not allowed on some types`.
>
> The answer is to “box” the value which forces it into a reference
> type, and then you can type check it:
>
> ```
> let detectTypeBoxed v =
>     match box v with      // used "box v"
>         | :? int -> printfn "this is an int"
>         | _ -> printfn "something else"
>
> //test
> detectTypeBoxed 1
> detectTypeBoxed 3.14
> ```

##### 2. Interoperability with non-F# .NET projects

The Functional Adam post [What is `box` in F#?](http://www.functionaladam.com/2016/04/what-is-box-in-f.html) nicely complements the example in the question:

> **The Problem** - The variable was in `Int`, it was required, and if it was not provided, our application was supposed to return an error
> code. When the parameter was not provided, [WebAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/) would set the
> required parameter to `null` even though `Int` cannot be `null`. This
> was very confusing, and, to make matters worse, we were not able to
> make the required parameter a `Nullable<Int>` with [WebAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/).
>
> **The Solution** - Box is the solution! From our searching, by boxing the `int` we could check if it is `null` even though it's not nullable
> (confusing). But what does the box function do? According to [[the
> docs](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-operators.html#box)], the `box` function in F# "*boxes a strongly typed value*".
> Ok... Thanks documentation.
>
> That's not all very helpful, but with further digging in [the [Boxing
> and Unboxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) article of the C# Programming Guide], the answer is
>
> > **Boxing is the process of converting a [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) to the type `object`** or to any interface type implemented by this value type.
> > When the [common language runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/clr) (CLR) boxes a [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types),
> > **it wraps the value inside a [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object) instance and stores it on the managed heap**. Unboxing extracts the [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) from
> > the object. Boxing is implicit; unboxing is explicit. The concept of
> > boxing and unboxing underlies the C# unified view of the type system
> > in which a value of any type can be treated as an object.
>
> So, boxing a value wraps the value type inside a [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object)
> and therefore we can check if the object is `null`. Then we have to
> unbox it back to an `Int` after the `null` check.