# What is a "sealed" type in F# and why doesn't the type test pattern operator (:?) work on it out of the `box`?

Tags: f#

The [F# language guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/) (see [Signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/signature-files) article) has a very sparse definition of what a "sealed" type is:

> | Attribute | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | `[<Sealed>]` | For a type that has no abstract members, or that should not be extended. |
> | `[<Interface>]` | For a type that is an interface. |

I searched the entire [PDF version of the language guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/pdf?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Ffsharp%2Ftoc.json) using the term `seal`, and this was the most informative (out of all 8 results).

#### Context: `:?` fails on "simple types" with `error FS0016`

For example, I was playing with type abbreviations when both matches failed

```
type Lofa = | A | B
type Miez = Lofa

let (a: Miez) = A

match a with | :? Miez -> a
match a with | :? Lofa -> a
```

with

```
error FS0016: The type 'Miez' does not  have any
proper subtypes and cannot be used as the source
of a type test or runtime coercion.

error FS0016: The type 'Lofa' does not  have any
proper subtypes and cannot be used as the source
of a type test or runtime coercion.
```

The SO thread [F# Why can't I use the :? operator in F# interactive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452303/f-why-cant-i-use-the-operator-in-f-interactive) provides an answer (i.e., to use `box`, hence the mnemonic pun in the title),

```
match (box a) with | :? Miez -> a
match (box a) with | :? Lofa -> a
```

but it doesn't explain why it works or what "sealed" types are, and also raises questions:

- Does this mean that "sealed" types are "simple" F# types (i.e., not defined as "class types")?

  Found the [issue #1320: Allow types to be Sealed by default](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/1320), but I think that it only proposes "class" types to be "sealed" by default (as the  "simple" types already are). Then again, this may be a misinterpretation.
- [I thought I understood what the `box` operator does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77765728/what-does-fs-box-keyword-do-and-where-is-it-documented) (even mentioned the same scenario there), but just realized that I don't know what "*`box` a returns value a wrapped in a .NET `System.Object` instance*" means.

  Does "wrapping" mean that a `box`ed "simple" F# type is redefined the same way as the original input, but as a "class type", inheriting everything from `System.Object`?

---

#### Note on possible duplicates

Yes, there are two questions in the title, but please consider my reasoning: I tried to separate and link the questions bidirectionally, but

- an abstract answer to the first one (similar to the guide's) without examples would probably just as unhelpful without context, and
- asking the second question would inevitable duplicate efforts to define what a "sealed" type is.

Answer (score 2):

A sealed type is one that may not be extended via inheritance. In other words, other types can't inherit from a sealed type. Since it's not possible to inherit from a discriminated union, `Lofa` and `Miez` are both sealed. If you want to seal an F# class type, however, you must explicitly mark it with the `[<Sealed>]` attribute.

The reason that `:?` can't be used on a sealed type is that its runtime type is guaranteed to be the same as its compile-time type:

```ml
let strStrong : string = "abc"       // strongly-typed value
printfn "%A" (strStrong :? string)   // not allowed, since the compiler knows it must be a string

let strWeak : obj = "abc"            // weakly-typed value
printfn "%A" (strWeak :? string)     // allowed, because it could be a non-string
```

Note that `box` (i.e. casting to `obj`) is just one way to create a weakly typed value. It also happens commonly with class hierarchies:

```ml
[<AbstractClass>]
type Animal =
    abstract member Sound : string

[<Sealed>]
type Dog =
    inherit Animal
    override _.Sound = "Woof"

type Cat =
    inherit Animal
    override _.Sound = "Meow"

let testAnimal (animal : Animal) =
    match animal with
        | :? Dog -> printfn "This is a dog"
        | _ -> printfn "Some other animal"

let testDog (dog : Dog) =
    match dog with
        | :? Dog -> printfn "This is a dog"   // not allowed, since we already know this is a Dog, and Dog is sealed
        | _ -> printfn "Impossible"

let testCat (cat : Cat) =
    match cat with
        | :? Cat -> printfn "This is a cat"   // allowed (with a warning), since Cat isn't sealed
        | _ -> printfn "Impossible"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sealed types are a .NET concept. They are types that cannot be inherited from. This includes:

- F# records
- F# unions
- F# classes declared with the `[<Sealed>]` attribute
- C# classes declared with the `sealed` keyword

---

Now, the `:?` operator tests whether a value is an instance of a given type. For example, if a variable `a` has statically known type `T`, and `U` is a subtype of `T`, then `a :? U` checks whether `a` is type `U`. It's false if `a` is a concrete `T` or another subtype of `T`.

But if `T` is sealed, then it has no subtype. So the expression `a :? U` is trivially false. Unless `U` is `T` or a supertype of `T`, in which case it's trivially true. Either way, it's a useless test. So the F# compiler assumes you made a mistake.

The expression `box a`, on the other hand, upcasts `a` to type `obj`. This type is not sealed (obviously, since all other types inherit from it). So there's nothing wrong with using `:?` on it.